# Magento installation redirect loop

Tags: magento, nginx, php, magento-1.8

I tried to install Magento Community Edition to my VPS(on Linode) with Nginx and php-fpm but I couldn't. I downloaded Magento 1.8.1.0 to my server. I created nginx configurations like [Magento Wiki](http://www.magentocommerce.com/wiki/1_-_installation_and_configuration/configuring_nginx_for_magento). But when I request my domain, it redirects to '/index.php/install/' path by 302 header and browser gives infinite loop error.

Can you suggest a workaround about that?

EDIT: My nginx configuration file (I replaced real domain name as mydomain)

```
server {
  server_name mydomain.com www.mydomain.com;
  root "/home/mydomain/public_html";

  index index.php;
  client_max_body_size 10m;

    access_log /home/mydomain/_logs/access.log;
    error_log /home/mydomain/_logs/error.log;

    if ($http_user_agent ~* (Baiduspider|webalta|nikto|wkito|pikto|scan|acunetix|morfeus|webcollage|youdao) ) {
       return 401;
    }

    if ($http_user_agent ~* (HTTrack|clshttp|archiver|loader|email|harvest|extract|grab|miner) ) {
       return 401;
    }

    location / {
        index index.html index.php; ## Allow a static html file to be shown first
        try_files $uri $uri/ @handler; ## If missing pass the URI to Magento's front handler
        expires 30d; ## Assume all files are cachable
    }

    ## These locations would be hidden by .htaccess normally
    location ^~ /app/                { deny all; }
    location ^~ /includes/           { deny all; }
    location ^~ /lib/                { deny all; }
    location ^~ /media/downloadable/ { deny all; }
    location ^~ /pkginfo/            { deny all; }
    location ^~ /report/config.xml   { deny all; }
    location ^~ /var/                { deny all; }

    location /var/export/ { ## Allow admins only to view export folder
        auth_basic           "Restricted"; ## Message shown in login window
        auth_basic_user_file htpasswd; ## See /etc/nginx/htpassword
        autoindex            on;
    }

    location  /. { ## Disable .htaccess and other hidden files
        return 404;
    }

    location @handler { ## Magento uses a common front handler
        rewrite / /index.php;
    }

    location ~ .php/ { ## Forward paths like /js/index.php/x.js to relevant handler
        rewrite ^(.*.php)/ $1 last;
    }

    location ~ "^(.+\.php)($|/)" {
        if (!-e $request_filename) { rewrite / /index.php last;  }

        fastcgi_param SCRIPT_FILENAME $document_root$fastcgi_script_name;
        fastcgi_param MAGE_RUN_CODE default;
        fastcgi_param MAGE_RUN_TYPE store;
        fastcgi_param HTTPS $https;

        fastcgi_pass   unix:/var/run/mydomain_fpm.sock;
        include        fastcgi_params;
    }


    location ~* \.(js|css|png|jpg|jpeg|gif|ico)$ {
            expires max;
            log_not_found off;
            access_log off;
    }

    location ~* \.(html|htm)$ {
        expires 30m;
    }

    location ~* /\.(ht|git|svn) {
        deny  all;
    }
}
```

Comment: Can you provide more details in to your nginx config?

Comment: I added nginx configuration file.

Answer (score 0):

Basicly, if you do not have crated database yet, it will be problem in Nginx and virtual hosting configuration.

Possible fault will be in memory of your browser. Try to clean it up, or use anonymous regime.

Try to remove magento files and create a simple index.php file with "hello" text inside. If it works try to copy Magento files again to this folder and run installation.

Have on mind, you MUST create a empty database with user having all rights to this database.

Second issue can be in fault installation, (Your magento is installed yet, and you trying to connect installer again, but this will redirect). In this case is something wrong in installation, remove tables from database and run installation again.

Answer (score 0):

My file looks like this:

```
server {
    listen 80 default;
    access_log /var/log/nginx/test.ssl.access.log;
    error_log /var/log/nginx/test.ssl.error.log;
    ssl off;
    root /var/www/shop;
    server_name sales.test.net.au;
    location / {
        index index.html index.php;
        try_files $uri $uri/ @handler;
        expires 30d;
    }
    location ^~ /app/ { deny all; }
    location ^~ /includes/ { deny all; }
    location ^~ /lib/ { deny all; }
    location ^~ /media/downloadable/ { deny all; }
    location ^~ /pkginfo/ { deny all; }
    location ^~ /report/config.xml { deny all; }
    location ^~ /var/ { deny all; }
    location /var/export/ { ## Allow admins only to view export folder
        auth_basic "Restricted"; ## Message shown in login window
        auth_basic_user_file htpasswd; ## See /etc/nginx/htpassword
        autoindex on;
    }
    location /. { ## Disable .htaccess and other hidden files
        return 404;
    }
    location @handler { ## Magento uses a common front handler
        rewrite / /index.php;
    }
    location ~ .php/ { ## Forward paths like /js/index.php/x.js to relevant handler
        rewrite ^(.*.php)/ $1 last;
    }
    location ~ .php$ { ## Execute PHP scripts
        if (!-e $request_filename) { rewrite / /index.php last; }
        expires off; ## Do not cache dynamic content
        fastcgi_pass 127.0.0.1:9000;
        fastcgi_param HTTPS $fastcgi_https;
        fastcgi_param SCRIPT_FILENAME $document_root$fastcgi_script_name;
        fastcgi_param MAGE_RUN_CODE default;
        fastcgi_param MAGE_RUN_TYPE store;
        include fastcgi_params;
    }
    location /phpmyadmin {
               root /usr/share/;
               index index.php index.html index.htm;
               location ~ ^/phpmyadmin/(.+\.php)$ {
                       try_files $uri =404;
                       root /usr/share/;
                       fastcgi_pass 127.0.0.1:9000;
                       fastcgi_index index.php;
                       fastcgi_param SCRIPT_FILENAME $document_root$fastcgi_script_name;
                       include /etc/nginx/fastcgi_params;
               }
               location ~* ^/phpmyadmin/(.+\.(jpg|jpeg|gif|css|png|js|ico|html|xml|txt))$ {
                       root /usr/share/;
               }
        }
        location /phpMyAdmin {
               rewrite ^/* /phpmyadmin last;
        }
}
server {
    listen 443 default;
    ssl on;
    ssl_certificate /etc/nginx/ssl/server.crt;
    ssl_certificate_key /etc/nginx/ssl/server.key;
    access_log /var/log/nginx/test.ssl.access.log;
    error_log /var/log/nginx/test.ssl.error.log;
    server_name sales.test.net.au;
    root /var/www/shop;
    location / {
        index index.html index.php;
        try_files $uri $uri/ @handler;
        expires 30d;
    }
    location ^~ /app/ { deny all; }
    location ^~ /includes/ { deny all; }
    location ^~ /lib/ { deny all; }
    location ^~ /media/downloadable/ { deny all; }
    location ^~ /pkginfo/ { deny all; }
    location ^~ /report/config.xml { deny all; }
    location ^~ /var/ { deny all; }
    location /var/export/ { ## Allow admins only to view export folder
        auth_basic "Restricted"; ## Message shown in login window
        auth_basic_user_file htpasswd; ## See /etc/nginx/htpassword
        autoindex on;
    }
    location /. { ## Disable .htaccess and other hidden files
        return 404;
    }
    location @handler { ## Magento uses a common front handler
        rewrite / /index.php;
    }
    location ~ .php/ { ## Forward paths like /js/index.php/x.js to relevant handler
        rewrite ^(.*.php)/ $1 last;
    }
    location ~ .php$ { ## Execute PHP scripts
        if (!-e $request_filename) { rewrite / /index.php last; }
        expires off; ## Do not cache dynamic content
        fastcgi_pass 127.0.0.1:9000;
        fastcgi_param HTTPS $fastcgi_https;
        fastcgi_param SCRIPT_FILENAME $document_root$fastcgi_script_name;
        fastcgi_param MAGE_RUN_CODE default;
        fastcgi_param MAGE_RUN_TYPE store;
        include fastcgi_params;
    }
    location /phpmyadmin {
               root /usr/share/;
               index index.php index.html index.htm;
               location ~ ^/phpmyadmin/(.+\.php)$ {
                       try_files $uri =404;
                       root /usr/share/;
                       fastcgi_pass 127.0.0.1:9000;
                       fastcgi_index index.php;
                       fastcgi_param SCRIPT_FILENAME $document_root$fastcgi_script_name;
                       include /etc/nginx/fastcgi_params;
               }
               location ~* ^/phpmyadmin/(.+\.(jpg|jpeg|gif|css|png|js|ico|html|xml|txt))$ {
                       root /usr/share/;
               }
        }
        location /phpMyAdmin {
               rewrite ^/* /phpmyadmin last;
        }
}
```

worked for me...

Comment: You could potentially have a permissions problem too... Set everything to 777, try that, and set permissions back to normal again...

Answer (score 0):

The problem was that "default" row had "https", and "stores" row had "http".

Use PhpMyAdmin to execute this SQL command:

```
SELECT * FROM `core_config_data` WHERE path like '%secure/base_url'
```

Then check that all secure rows start with "https".

Answer (score -2):

Please check with your htaccess file. If it exists please check the existing rules

Comment: Nginx doesn't have .htaccess :|